# How to pass argument to componentDidMount method in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to take input from the user through a button in App.js, fetch some information(the data id) from the site API and then use the fetched information(the id) to display the desired info to user by sending the id to Population.js but it just isn't working correctly. I am thinking that probably the componentDidUpdate needs some argument because the fetch request that I have to send needs user input to work.Also, I think that my code is fetching information even before user presses the button because the console isn't displaying the correct id that I need(it displays 4-5 values and all are not correct). It works fine if I hardcode the values though.Basically, I want to take input through button, use that input to fetch something, then use the fetched thing to fetch something else and then display the fetched info.Please help me. I am a beginner at React.
Here is the APP.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Population from './Population.js';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { name: "" ,info : {},formSubmit: false};
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    }   
    
      handleInput (event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
      }
    
      handleFormSubmit (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("the value " + event.target.value);
        this.setState({formSubmit: true,name : event.target.value});
      }
      
        componentDidMount(){//the value property needs to be fetched from user 
        fetch(`https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities?namePrefix=${value}`, {
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "x-rapidapi-key": "c4ab967692mshc65dd5c6e10a987p1790bejsn81ea7b831444",
                "x-rapidapi-host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com"
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const newInfo = data.data;
            const newName = newInfo[0].wikiDataId;
            const newState = Object.assign({},this.state,{
                info : newInfo,
                name : newName
            });
            this.setState(newState);
            console.log("The sent code " + this.state.name);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
      }

      render () {

        return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>
                Enter the name of the city: <br/>
            </h1>
            <form >
              <label>
                Enter the city name to get the population:{" "}
                <input
                  type="text"
                />
                <button onClick = {this.handleFormSubmit}>Enter</button>  
                  
              </label>
              
            </form>
            {this.state.formSubmit && <Population name={this.state.name} />}
          </div>
        );

      }
}

export default App;
```

and here is the Population.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./App.css";
class Population extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            info : {},
            population : 0,
        }
        this.getPopulation = this.getPopulation.bind(this);
    }

    getPopulation(name){
        fetch(`https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/${name}`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
           "x-rapidapi-key": "c4ab967692mshc65dd5c6e10a987p1790bejsn81ea7b831444",
           "x-rapidapi-host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com"
            }   
        })
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then((data) => {
           const newInfo = data.data;
           const newPopulation = newInfo.population;
           const newState = Object.assign({},this.state,{
               info : newInfo,
               population : newPopulation
           });
           this.setState(newState);
           console.log(this.state.info);
       })
       .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getPopulation(this.props.name);
        console.log("The name " + this.props.name);

    }

   render(){
    return (
        <div className="App">
            The population is {this.state.population}
        </div>
        );
    }

}
export default Population;
```

Comment: You have the fetch in both components, which one do you want to use to call the service? and you say that you need user input, how are you getting that?

Comment: I am using button in App.js to get input. The input will be used to fetch an id in the componentDidMount method in App.js and that input will be passed to Pollution.js to fetch and display the required data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is different and you dont have to use componentDidMount here as you are going to do the service call after the user presses the search button.

I have modified your code to work on button press and it passes a code to the population component which does a call to api on both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate as the code may be update in future

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "", info: {}, formSubmit: false, code: "" };
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
     this.setState({ name: event.target.value, formSubmit: false });
  }

  handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch(
      `https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities?namePrefix=${this.state.name}`,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "x-rapidapi-key":
            "",
          "x-rapidapi-host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const newInfo = data.data;
        const newName = newInfo[0].wikiDataId;
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          info: newInfo[0],
          code: newName,
          formSubmit: true
        });
        this.setState(newState);
        console.log("The sent code " + this.state.name);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    //the value property needs to be fetched from user
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>
          Enter the name of the city: <br />
        </h1>
        <form>
          <label>
            Enter the city name to get the population:{" "}
            <input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.name}
              onChange={this.handleInput}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>Enter</button>
          </label>
        </form>
        {this.state.formSubmit && <Population name={this.state.code} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the population component would be like

```
class Population extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      info: {},
      population: 0
    };
    this.getPopulation = this.getPopulation.bind(this);
  }

  getPopulation(name) {
    fetch(`https://wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/geo/cities/${name}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "wft-geo-db.p.rapidapi.com"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const newInfo = data.data;
        const newPopulation = newInfo.population;
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          info: newInfo,
          population: newPopulation
        });
        this.setState(newState);
        console.log(this.state.info);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.name) {
      this.getPopulation(this.props.name);
      console.log("The name " + this.props.name);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.name) {
      this.getPopulation(this.props.name);
      console.log("The name " + this.props.name);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App">The population is {this.state.population}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've removed the api key from the answer as its public

Comment: Thanks. It served my purpose. I understood. Is there any way that that I can make the Population.js wait for some time and then send the fetch request when it gets the code?.Right now I think, as soon as it gets the code, it sends the fetch request.The website allows 1 request per second so console says that I exceeded my requests

Comment: you can use a setTimeout and do it after a given time

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I had never heard of it before. But it should work. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

The componentDidMount function is called as soon as the component mounts and hence it is performing the fetch operation as soon as the component mounts. If you want the fetch operation to occur on a button click you will have to place the code inside a custom function and call it on button click. I don't think you can pass any props to component did mount as you cannot control when it is called. The componentDidUpdate might be of use to you
[componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate)